# How to print Upcoming 4 Fridays in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am wring a PowerShell to print dates of upcoming 4 Fridays.

```
$date = Get-Date
for ($num = 1 ; $num -le 4 ; $num++){ 
while ($Date.DayOfWeek -ne "Friday") {$date = $date.AddDays($num)}
$datestr = $date.ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')
echo $datestr
$SomeVar = "Friday - " + $num + " - " + $datestr
echo $SomeVar
}
```

Output :

```
04-11-2022
Friday - 1 - 04-11-2022
04-11-2022
Friday - 2 - 04-11-2022
04-11-2022
Friday - 3 - 04-11-2022
04-11-2022
Friday - 4 - 04-11-2022
```

Here I am able to print the single date of upcoming Friday. But, I wanted to print the dates of upcoming 4 Fridays.

Can you please help me out what I am missing or any better way to Print Dates Upcoming Specific day.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're making this too difficult.

Try

```
# skip if today happens to be a Friday too, because you want 'upcoming'
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(1)  
# while $date is not a Friday, keep adding days to it
while ($date.DayOfWeek -ne 'Friday') { $date = $date.AddDays(1) }

# next output the 4 upcoming Fridays
for ($i = 1; $i -le 4; $i++) {
    Write-Host "$($date.DayOfWeek) - $i - $($date.ToString('dd-MM-yyyy'))"
    $date = $date.AddDays(7)
}
```

Output:

```
Friday - 1 - 04-11-2022
Friday - 2 - 11-11-2022
Friday - 3 - 18-11-2022
Friday - 4 - 25-11-2022
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date variable is being replaced with a string variable.  Consider naming the new variable to reflect what it contains:

```
$dateStr = $date.ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')
```

Comment: The type casting did get resolved resolved however the dates are still not getting populated. Can you please suggest the changes in the script

Answer (score 0):

```
# Determine the input date.
$date = Get-Date

# Find the next Friday relative to the input date (which may be that date itself).
$nextFriday = $date.AddDays(([DayOfWeek]::Friday - $date.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7)

# Output the next Friday plus the 3 ones after that (4 in total).
0..3 | ForEach-Object { $nextFriday.AddDays(7 * $_) }
```

The above outputs [`[datetime]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) instances, which you can format as needed.